# How to parse array inside variable in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

I have a returned variable `$returned_variable` that contains

```
{
    "companies": [{
                "id": "4127303000000527195",
                "company_name": "235 St Georges Landowning Trust & Australian City Properties Pty Ltd"
            }, {
                "id": "4127303000004495043",
                "company_name": "Bourke Junction No 1 Pty Ltd"
            }, {
                "id": "4127303000000527189",
                "company_name": "Brookfield Commercial Operations Pty Ltd"
            }, {
                "id": "4127303000000527063",
                "company_name": "GPT Property Management Pty Limited"
            }, {
                "id": "4127303000000527045",
                "company_name": "Investa Nominees (2) Pty Ltd & The Trustee for PSS/CSS A Property Trust"
            }, {
                "id": "4127303000012031116",
                "company_name": "Krys Co"
            }, {
                "id": "4127303000000527033",
                "company_name": "Lend Lease IMT (OITST ST) Pty Ltd as The Trustee for LL One"
            }
            ]
}
```

How can I parse it so I can use id and company_name as a separate variable ?

I've try `json_decode` but it doesnt work because its considering it as a whole text.

Comment: If "it doesnt work because its considering it as a whole text" was meant to allude to a concrete problem, then some sample code is necessary. See [mcve]

Comment: reading between the lines it seems your after [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).. https://3v4l.org/TXdkG

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

```
json_decode($returned_variable, true);
```

Comment: it's working. try it